# Sort a table column where the header has whitspace

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular based table which I would like to sort by one of the columns

If I sort by the column Reference this line works

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in documentaryCreditsTable.rows | orderBy:'-Reference'">
```

However I would like to sort by a column named 'Expiry date' and I'm assuming that since this column has a space I'm getting the following error:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="row in documentaryCreditsTable.rows | orderBy:'-Expiry date'">
```

Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'date' is an unexpected token at column 8 of the expression [Expiry date] starting at [date].

Any idea how to work around that as this String is what is presented to the user on the screen and I would like to keep the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
var sortBy = 'Expiry date';
$scope.predicate = function(val) {
  return -val[sortBy];
}
```

View:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in documentaryCreditsTable.rows | orderBy:predicate">
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.